# Calabash-Elements are not identified using Query command, but identified using UIAutomator.bat

Tags: calabash-android

I am using Calabash automation tool for one of the client application (android) testing. i am facing the following issue: 
my script is failing because Elements in login page are not identified using query command (query("*")), but the same elements are identified in UIAutomator view.
can any one suggest me the solution for this issue

very much appreciated your help

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Query-Language

By default Calabash will query only visible views (determined by a heuristic - not 100% bullet proof). If you want to change the behavior to query all views you simply prepend the modifier all.

```
query("all button")
query("all view marked:'something'")
```

Note: there is also a function query_all which is deprecated.